# Issue with URL hitting

Tags: java, android

i got issue with URL and getting null as response.I have also tried to Make it Encode but reponce is not getting as per expectation..

**Here is my code :**

```
try
     {          
         String url = "http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=Thanks&langpair=EN|KO" + query;
         Log.i("URL", ">>>"+url);
         JSONObject Responce = getJSONfromURL(url.toString());
         Log.e("", "Responce"+Responce);
     }
     catch (Exception e) {}
```

**Error Log:**

```
10-12 20:13:35.411: INFO/URL(6844): >>>http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=Thanks&langpair=EN|KO
10-12 20:13:35.531: ERROR/log_tag(6844): Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 59: http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=Thanks&langpair=EN|KO
10-12 20:13:35.531: ERROR/log_tag(6844): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 20:13:35.531: ERROR/log_tag(6844): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-12 20:13:35.541: ERROR/(6844): Responcenull
```

**After Encoding**

URL Encode method apply..

```
    String query = URLEncoder.encode("Thanks&langpair=EN|KO", "utf-8");
    String url = "http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=" + query;
    Log.i("URL", ">>>"+url);
    JSONObject Responce = getJSONfromURL(url.toString());
    Log.e("", "Responce"+Responce);
```

**Log ::**

```
10-12 20:21:01.180: INFO/URL(7050): >>>http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=Thanks%26langpair%3DEN%7CKO
10-12 20:21:01.710: ERROR/(7050): Responce{"responseData":{"translatedText":"INVALID LANGUAGE PAIR SPECIFIED. EXAMPLE: LANGPAIR=EN|IT USING 2 LETTER ISO OR RFC3066 LIKE ZH-CN. ALMOST ALL LANGUAGES SUPPORTED BUT SOME MAY HAVE NO CONTENT"},"matches":"","responseStatus":403,"responseDetails":"INVALID LANGUAGE PAIR SPECIFIED. EXAMPLE: LANGPAIR=EN|IT USING 2 LETTER ISO OR RFC3066 LIKE ZH-CN. ALMOST ALL LANGUAGES SUPPORTED BUT SOME MAY HAVE NO CONTENT"}
```

Comment: try opening this http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=Thanks&langpair=EN|KO in a web broswer.. it's working fine with some valid response. if I append any thing at the end to this URL it gives me the same response that you mentioned under `Log ::`  So I think the issue is with value of `query` variable which is not valid for server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't URLEncode the "=" in your query string. Essentially, you just want to urlEncode the values. So if your URL looked like this, it would work:

```
http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=Thanks&langpair=EN%7CKO
```